# Apply policy to all but specific users OR computers

Tags: group-policy, active-directory-group

Specifically I'm trying to implement a block removable storage policy.

Let's say I have 100 computers named PC1-PC100. PC1-PC10 need to allow removable storage no matter whom logs in. Additionally, a couple user accounts need access to removable storage no matter what computer they log into.

I have tried this by creating a security group, adding the computers list to it, creating a policy that targets Authenticated Users which blocks removable storage at the user level, and then added delegations for the whitelisted computer security group and the 2 user accounts, with a Deny for Apply Group Policy. The delegations worked for the 2 user accounts, but removable storage did not work on the computers in the security group unless the 2 mentioned accounts were logged in.

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this would be better asked on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).